# How to re-render the same page with additional data

Tags: node.js, express

I have two routing functions that have to render the same page but with different data based on the URL.But once I have rendered a page, I am unable to re-render the page, it throws an error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I have two routes like this

```
app.post('/abc',function(req,res){
...
res.render('template',{....})
...
});

app.get('/abc/xyz/:params',function(req,res){
...
res.render('template',{...})
...
});
```

I have a submit button on the `/abc` page that directs to `/abc/xyz/params` but it gives me the header error.

Then, I tried to send some data with `res.json` which I could later handle with AJAX, but once the submit button is pressed the rendered page is lost and hence it only returns a JSON file.

I actually am trying to update a portion of a page without reloading the whole thing,but I am unable to preserve the template once the submit button is pressed.

I even tried the HTML5 History API to change URL without refresh but that even gives me the same error.

**This is my whole code**

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){

    dbo.collection("user").find({$and:[{"email":req.body.email},{'password':req.body.password}]}).count().then(function(result){
      if(result==1){
        dbo.collection("user").findOne({$and:[{"email":req.body.email},{'password':req.body.password}]}, function(err, r) {
        req.session.email=req.body.email;
          if (err) throw err;
          res.render('login', {name:r.name,email:  req.body.email,password: req.body.password,status: "Match Found!"});

        });
      }
      else{
        console.log('Match not found');
        res.render('error_msg', { email:  req.body.email,password: req.body.password,status: "Match Not found!"});
      }
    });
});



app.get('/login/email/:email',function(req,res){
  dbo.collection("user").findOne({"email":req.params.email},function(er,r){
    if(er) 
      throw er;
    if(r){
      res.render('login',{email_search:r.name});
    }
    else{
      res.render('login',{email_search:'No User Found!'});
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Show more code, with that code you can't get that error. You're ending the request twice, that's why you're getting that error, show more code.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I doubt that's your whole code, because the error doesn't happen in there. Show your other middlewares, you're ending the request twice. And that doesn't happen in those routes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was ending the request twice. Is there any way I can send json to the page without re-rendering ?  so that I can handle that with AJAX. Because when I re-render, the previous data variables are lost.

Comment: Show your full code, and I will tell you.